# Receiving an extremely long Token from server, how to make it multi lined so I don't have to drag the scroll bar in order to copy it?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I have a lengthy Token I'm logging from the server that I want to copy and paste it into Postman for testing the API. But it takes a good while to select with mouse, and slowly drag it to copy the entire String token. Is there a way to format the log so that it's multi lined, or is there a way to copy the entire token with a click?

Right now I'm using `Log.d(TAG, "GetUserToken: Token: " + mAccount.getIdToken());`

Double clicking only selects parts of the token until it reachs a period `.` or a hyphen `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag vertically (not horizontally) to select a whole line.

1. Place your cursor at the start of the line.
2. Keep holding the mouse button (or touch pad) down and drag to the next line.
3. You can select the whole line.

[image: screen capture]

Note: Instead of using your mouse or touch pad, you can also use the down-arrow key as pressing the shift key.